# How to sum one column based on key of two other columns

Tags: r, sum, dataframe

I have a data.frame with three columns:

```
To     Amount   Type
Smith  $1       A
John   $5       B
Jeff   $8       A
Smith  $4       C
...    ...      ...
```

And I need to convert it into a data frame that indicates how much money of each type each person received.

```
Name  TotalAmtOfTypeA  TotalAmtOfTypeB  TotalAmtOfTypeC ...
Smith $1               $0               $4
John  $0               $5               $0
Jeff  $8               $0               $0
...
```

The original data.frame is just over three million lines long, so the more efficient or parallelized the solution is, the better. Does the solution involve `aggregate`? Or should I look into `plyr`? Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: This solution involves "reshaping" the data frame. There is a base R `reshape` function, but if you want to learn the dplyr family tools, the package to use is `tidyr` (it is complementary to `dplyr`). Have a look at the function `spread()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two options:

```
library(tidyr)
spread(df, Type, Amount)
#     To ordered.A ordered.B ordered.C
#1  Jeff        $8      <NA>      <NA>
#2  John      <NA>        $5      <NA>
#3 Smith        $1      <NA>        $4
```

Or

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(df, To ~ Type, value.var = "Amount")
#     To    A    B    C
#1  Jeff   $8 <NA> <NA>
#2  John <NA>   $5 <NA>
#3 Smith   $1 <NA>   $4
```

Or, if you change the column class from factor to character, you can do:

```
df$Amount <- as.character(df$Amount)
dcast(df, To ~ Type, value.var = "Amount", fill = "$0")
#     To  A  B  C
#1  Jeff $8 $0 $0
#2  John $0 $5 $0
#3 Smith $1 $0 $4
```

And equally

```
spread(df, Type, Amount, fill = "$0")
#     To  A  B  C
#1  Jeff $8 $0 $0
#2  John $0 $5 $0
#3 Smith $1 $0 $4
```

Note: if you leave the "Amount" column as factor and try to use `fill = "$0"` you will get an error message like this:

> Warning message: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, is.na(ordered), value = 0) :
>   invalid factor level, NA generated

---

If you wanted to get rid of those "$" in your Amount column so that you can actually use those numbers for further processing, here's how you could do it in a dplyr / tidyr chain:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  mutate(Amount = as.numeric(gsub("\\$", "", Amount))) %>%
  spread(Type, Amount, fill = 0)

#     To A B C
#1  Jeff 8 0 0
#2  John 0 5 0
#3 Smith 1 0 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `data.table` solution which should work rather fast:

**Data**

```
library(data.table)
n <- 1e6
dat <- data.table(Name = LETTERS[sample(26, n, TRUE)],
                  Amount = rpois(n, 100),
                  Type = letters[sample(26, n, TRUE)])
```

**Code**

```
setkey(dat, Name, Type)
dat.agg <- dat[, .(Sum = sum(Amount)), by =.(Name, Type)]
dat.agg[, as.list(setattr(Sum, 'names', Type)), by = .(Name)]
```

**Explanation**

The first `[.data.table` aggregates teh `data.table` to have the sums of all `Name/Type` combinations. The second `[.data.table`, formats the `data.table` in the way you wanted it. The `setattr` is used to have a nice output (to anem the columns according to the levels of `Type`.

Comment: This seems exactly on the right track, but with my real data, I get  the error: `Error in \`[.data.table\`(pacdons2.agg, , as.list(setattr(Sum, "names",  : 
  j doesn't evaluate to the same number of columns for each group`